# How to use HTMX to update cart without refreshing the page after adding product to cart in Django

Tags: django, htmx

In Django I add to cart and favorites without refreshing the page, but my cart and favorites are not updating (it is updated when I refresh the page).

Please help I've been struggling with this for three days but failing every time I don't know what to change or add

favorites are almost the same this way

## here is the html add to cart button

```
{% for rs in trending_products_all %}
                            <div class="product product-11 text-center">
                                <figure class="product-media">
                                    <a href="{% url 'detail' rs.id rs.newSlug %}">
                                        <img src="{{rs.productImage.url}}" alt="Ürün resmi" class="product-image">
                                        
                                        {% comment %}
                                        {% for img in rs.images.all %}
                                        <img src="{{img.image.url}}" alt="Ürün resmi" class="product-image-hover">
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {% endcomment %}
                                        
                                    </a>

                                    <div class="product-action-vertical">
                                        <a class="btn-product-icon btn-wishlist update-favorite"  data-product="{{ rs.id }}" data-action="add"onclick="clickAddToFavoriButton(this); return false;"><span>Favorilere Ekle</span></a>
                                    </div><!-- End .product-action-vertical -->
                                </figure><!-- End .product-media -->

                                <div class="product-body">
                                    <h3 class="product-title"><a href="{% url 'detail' rs.id rs.newSlug %}">{{rs.productTitle|safe}}</a></h3><!-- End .product-title -->
                                    <div class="product-price">
                                        <b>{{rs.productPrice}} TL</b>
                                    </div><!-- End .product-price -->
                                </div><!-- End .product-body -->
                                <div class="product-action">
                                    <a class="btn-product btn-cart update-cart" data-product="{{ rs.id }}" data-action="add"onclick="clickAddToCartButton(this); return false;"><span>Add To Cart</span></a>
                                </div><!-- End .product-action -->
                            </div><!-- End .product -->
                            {% endfor %}
```

### **views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def f_update_item(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    _customer = request.user

    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    cartItem = CartModel.objects.filter(customer=_customer).filter(product_id=productId)
    if not cartItem:
        cartItem = CartModel.objects.create(product_id=productId, customer=_customer, amount=1)
        cartItem.save()
        
    else:
        cartItem = CartModel.objects.get(customer=_customer, product_id=productId)
        if action == "add":
            cartItem.amount += 1
        elif action == "remove":
            cartItem.amount -= 1
        cartItem.save()
        request.session['cart_items'] = CartModel.objects.filter(customer_id=request.user.id).count()
    return JsonResponse(
        "<div class='inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-8 h-8 text-green-500 bg-green-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-green-800 dark:text-green-200'><svg aria-hidden='true' class='w-5 h-5' fill='currentColor' viewBox='0 0 20 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z' clip-rule='evenodd'></path></svg><span class='sr-only'>Check icon</span></div><div class='ml-3 text-md font-normal'>Ürün sepete başarıyla eklenmiştir.</div><button @click='dismissed=true' type='button' class='ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-300 p-1.5 hover:bg-gray-100 inline-flex h-8 w-8 dark:text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700' data-dismiss-target='#toast-success' aria-label='Close'><span class='sr-only'>Close</span><svg aria-hidden='true' class='w-5 h-5' fill='currentColor' viewBox='0 0 20 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z' clip-rule='evenodd'></path></svg></button>",
        safe=False)
```

**cart.js**

```
function clickAddToCartButton(target) {
    //   var target = event.target;
    var productId = target.dataset.product;
    var action = target.dataset.action;
    console.log("product ID:", productId, "Action: ", action);
    console.log("USER: ", user);
    if (user == "AnonymousUser") {
      console.log("Kullanıcı giriş yapmamış");
    } else {
      updateUserOrder(productId, action);
    }
  }
  function updateUserOrder(productId, action) {
    console.log("Giriş yapıldı ve sepete ekleniyor");
    var url = "/user/update_item/";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ productId: productId, action: action }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var message = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(message);
        message.className = "flex items-center w-full fixed top-10 right-5  max-w-md p-4 mb-4 text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800 productCartAdd";
        message.innerHTML = data;
        setTimeout(() => {
          message.classList.add("closing-effect");
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function () {
          message.remove();
        }, 4000);
      });
  }
```

Comment: you need to read this carefully: https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/ . Also, I don't understand why you have cart.js. Why have custom JavaScript when you're using HTMX?